# Bad Performance of QPainter::drawText on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, qt, text, transformation

I have noticed that QPainter::drawText is horribly slow on Linux when using it with a scaled window mapping. Is there anything I can do about this? I already checked whether disabling anti-aliasing or enabled the raster-renderer makes a difference, but it doesn't.

Example: When using a viewport size of (450px, 200px), a window size of factor 100 (45000, 20000) and thus font sizes scaled up by factor 100 as well (1400pt), rendering 30 times the text "hello" takes about 4(!) seconds on Linux - both on OpenSuse and Ubuntu.

The same sample renders in a snap on Windows and Mac.

Just for clarification: although the font size is scaled up, the text appears in "normal" size on screen due to the described window<->viewport mapping.

Here is the simple sample code I am using:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    const int scaleFactor = 100;

    QPainter painter(this);

    // Setup font
    QFont font;
    font.setPointSize(14*scaleFactor);
    painter.setFont(font);

    // Setup mapping
    painter.setWindow(0, 0, width() * scaleFactor, height() * scaleFactor);

    // Render the text
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        painter.drawText(qrand() % (width() * scaleFactor), qrand() % (height() * scaleFactor), "Hello");
}
```

Any help would be awesome.

Note: I am using Qt 4.8.5

Comment: Did you try to scale painter with `painter.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);` instead of setting window rectangle? Does it make difference?

Comment: I did a quick test right now. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ok. Than maybe you could think of a limit the drawing area by the visible one that is much smaller than 45000x20000px?

Comment: The drawing area in pixel is not 45000x20000. It is just 450x200px. The "virtual" window size is 45000x20000, which then gets mapped to the 450x200px viewport by QPainter. Thus, rendering 30 times "Hello" in a 450x200 rectangle takes about 4 seconds on Linux (when using mapping/transformations).

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's a Qt bug, and you should report it.

Comment: I have posted a Qt bugreport about this: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36745

Comment: Update: QRasterPaintEngine::drawTextItem() contains a snippet which falls back to drawTextItem() if the QFontEngine is not of type FreeType. Removing this snippet, which means that drawCachedGlyphs will be used instead, fixes the performance problem. Any way to bypass this fallback without modifying the Qt source? Note: the font looks quite badly rendered with the above hack (like without anti aliasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found!

The FontConfig developer libraries where not installed on my Linux system. This caused Qt to be built against XLFD, which obviously doesn't work well with scaled mappings (see report above).

After installing the FontConfig dev libs and rebuilding Qt the text now gets rendered nice and fast. I did additionally specify the "-fontconfig" parameter when rebuilding Qt, just to be sure, but according to the Qt guys this shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old but as be Qt bug still seems to be unresolved here we go...

Not sure if this might be an option but in two projects I worked for we implemented labels which internally rendered into a pimap/image first which was then drawn.
So caching your text in an image whith transparent background should solve the problem.

I do not think it makes a difference here, but you might also check if QStaticText has a beneficial influence on performance in your case.

Comment: Good idea - I have tested this right away. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Interestingly it ends up on the same rendering path. The relevant difference between Win and Linux seems to be in RasterPaintEngine::drawTextItem(). On Windows this method calls drawCachedGlyphs() which copies the cached glyph in screen space. On Linux it uses QPaintEngineEx::drawTextItem() which renders the glyph in windows space and thus *really* large.